# RxJava не выходит сделать повторение в Observable

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Я пытаюсь создать `Observable`, который загружает файл 10 раз через секунду и отдает результат в `Subscriber`. Однако, `Observable` загружает файл единожды.  Вот код:

```
        Observable.create((subscriber) -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Загрузка начинается");
            mDownloadHelper.downloadFile(
                    mSharedPreferences.getString(DOC_URL_KEY, ""),
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    new DownloadHelper.DownloadListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDownloaded(Uri fileUri) {
                            subscriber.onNext(fileUri);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailed() {
                            subscriber.onError(new Exception("Не выходит загрузить файл"));
                        }
                    });

            Log.i(TAG, "Загрузка началась");
        })
                .repeat(10)
                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Object o) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Загрузился!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Ошибка!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Завершился"); //Не должно быть
                    }
                });
```

В результате вывод лог такой:

```
10-23 15:04:24.744 24859-24886/com.dugin.rostislav.reminderofwork.doc_handling_service I/RLOG: Загрузка начинается
10-23 15:04:24.866 24859-24886/com.dugin.rostislav.reminderofwork.doc_handling_service I/RLOG: Загрузка началась
10-23 15:04:26.515 24859-24888/com.dugin.rostislav.reminderofwork.doc_handling_service I/RLOG: Загрузился!
```

---

В чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, повтора не будет пока задача не завершится. Т.е. попробуйте после скачивания файла вызвать

```
subscriber.onCompleted();
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/116692)

Comment: О, Юрий! А вы все еще тут обитаете? :)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, как показала практика это вполне себе ответ. Просто он не всегда должен быть длинным и полным уверенности в своей правильности)

Comment: @bukashka101, ну да... Это вы куда-то пропали)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сначала пошел читать тех. литературу (дочитал философию, Effective Java, Совершенный код и т.д.), а потом пошел писать свой проект.

Comment: @bukashka101, эх... А у меня руки только до пары книг по синтаксису дошли... Да и то давно это было) И как ваш проект?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, весьма печально.. :)) Но в процессе.